# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when i run my compiled program

Tags: c++

I have this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Flacon
{
private:
  string nom;
  double volume;
  double pH;

public:
    Flacon(string nom, double volume, double pH): nom(nom), volume(volume), pH(pH) {}
    ostream& etiquette(ostream&) const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const Flacon &);
    friend Flacon& operator+(Flacon const&, Flacon const&);

};


Flacon& operator+(Flacon const& f1, Flacon const& f2){
    Flacon f3(f1.nom + " " + f2.nom, f1.volume + f2.volume, -log10((f1.volume * pow(10,-f1.pH) + f2.volume * pow(10,-f2.pH))/(f1.volume + f2.volume)));
    return f3;
}

ostream& Flacon::etiquette(ostream& sortie) const {
    sortie << nom << " : " << volume << " ml, pH " << pH;
    return sortie;}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const Flacon & f){
    f.etiquette(o);
    return o;
}

/*******************************************
 * Ne rien modifier après cette ligne.
 *******************************************/

void afficher_melange(Flacon const& f1, Flacon const& f2)
{
  cout << "Si je mélange " << endl;
  cout << "\t\"" << f1 << "\"" << endl;
  cout << "avec" << endl;
  cout << "\t\"" << f2 << "\"" << endl;
  cout << "j'obtiens :" << endl;
  cout << "\t\"" << (f1 + f2) << "\"" << endl;
}

int main()
{
  Flacon flacon1("Eau", 600.0, 7.0);
  Flacon flacon2("Acide chlorhydrique", 500.0, 2.0);
  Flacon flacon3("Acide perchlorique",  800.0, 1.5);

  afficher_melange(flacon1, flacon2);
  afficher_melange(flacon2, flacon3);

  return 0;

}
```

And when I compile,I have this warning message :

> chimie.cc:23:9: warning: reference to local variable ‘f3’ returned
>   [-Wreturn-local-addr]   Flacon f3(f1.nom + " " + f2.nom, f1.volume +
>   f2.volume, -log10((f1.volume * pow(10,-f1.pH) + f2.volume *
>   pow(10,-f2.pH))/(f1.volume + f2.volume)));

And when I build :

> chimie.cc:23:9: warning: reference to local variable ‘f3’ returned
>   [-Wreturn-local-addr] Flacon f3(f1.nom + " " + f2.nom, f1.volume +
>   f2.volume, -log10((f1.volume * pow(10,-f1.pH) + f2.volume *
>   pow(10,-f2.pH))/(f1.volume + f2.volume)));

And when i Run :

> Si je mélange     "Eau : 600 ml, pH 7" avec   "Acide chlorhydrique : 500
>   ml, pH 2" j'obtiens : Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Your `operator+` returns a reference to a local variable (as per the compile warning). This variable goes out of scope once the method concludes, which explains the segmentation fault. What sort of lifetime do you intend for `f3`?

Comment: To fix this, you should define `operator+` as `Flacon operator+(Flacon const& f1, Flacon const& f2)` instead so that it returns the instance by value. Returning by value is optimized in modern C++ compilers so that instead of the assigment of the return value an in-place construction will happen.